# Is MetaWeblog API still supported?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, xml-rpc, metaweblog

Is the MetaWeblog API still supported? I ask because while researching XMLRPC, the Cook Computing library and implementing MetaWeblog API, I clicked a link that took me to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259697.aspx) that states the topic has been removed.

There is a link there that takes me to new docs for Windows Live SDK. On the new page i cannot find current info on MWAPI.

I am using EF, MV3, and VB.Net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MetaWeblog API support had always seemed (to me) tenuous at best.  Seeing as how the project hasn't been updated since 2003 (http://www.xmlrpc.com/metaWeblogApi) I think it is safe to assume that support has essentially ceased. That's my .02 anyway.

(Also, the Yahoo web group's newest post is from 2004 (http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/MetaWeblog-API/))

Comment: Interestingly Word 2013 offer this as a way to connect to generic blogging systems. It is good because even on Windows RT which does not allow plugins it is still supported.

Comment: Link on xmlRpc site is broken, but WordPress supports it https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_MetaWeblog_API